# Changing the route when opening a modal but not navigating to it

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[Instagram example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVW2j.png)

As in the image above, in the user profile page with a url(profile/:username), the user is able to click on one of his posts which opens a modal containing that specific post, the url thereafter changes to p/:postId but doesn't navigate to another page, it instead displays above the profile page without navigating to p/:postId

I'm trying to do the same in my app and I have tried doing stuff like history.push but it's not working and I assume this is happening cause of react-router.

Comment: do you are using react-router-dom library?

Comment: @AbbasBagheri yes.

Comment: It is rather difficult to address any issues with code we can't see. Please [edit] the post to include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working and have an issue with.

Comment: @DrewReese, so I don't have an issue with my code which is why I didn't include it, I would only like to know how to tackle my question using react-router, I don't think my code will help you in any sort of way. :D

Comment: I see. Well asking for suggestions and recommendations for what you ***should*** do is too open-ended and broad, and not really on-topic for Stackoverflow. If you have tried something already and have a specific programming question about a specific issue with an implementation then that's something you can ask about. You mentioned you *are* actually using `react-router-dom`, so IMHO including a [mcve] with the routing code/logic you are trying to apply is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the behavior you described, you can use React Router to manage the URL change and display the modal with the post content.

1. Define a route in your React Router configuration that corresponds to the modal content you want to display. For example

```
<Route path="/posts/:postId" component={PostModal} />
```

2. In your component, include a link to the new route with the post ID as a parameter.

```
<Link to={`/posts/${postId}`}>View Post</Link>
```

3. In your PostModal component, use the useParams hook to access the post ID parameter from the URL. Then, fetch the post data from your API or store, and display it.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function PostModal() {
  const { postId } = useParams();
  // Fetch post data and display it in modal
}
```

After that, Use CSS to display the modal as an overlay on top of your existing content, and use JavaScript to show and hide the modal as appropriate.

Comment: I might have not described my issue properly, I've already done what you've said above, so again:
I Have a route profile/:username where the user can see all his posts, what I want is when the user clicks on his post => it will open a modal containing the post,then I want the url to change to sth like post/:id without navigating to that route so that the modal with the changed route would still be displayed above the posts from profile/:username